# USB 2.0 UGA (displaylink) not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, displaylink

I performed the installation following the steps on the official displaylink website, but the device does not work. When I look for `lsusb`, the device shows as connected, but the monitor gives no signal. On windows it was working normally.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:2130 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
-> Bus 001 Device 007: ID 17e9:03c1 DisplayLink USB graphic adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30fa:1701 INSTANT USB GAMING MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```